# Why doesn't Animated.css work as explained on the website?

Tags: html, css, animation

I am trying to use an animation on my webpage, I followed the steps below but nothing happens when I checked the page.

Step 1: Link in HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css"/>
```

Step 2: Add the class animate__animated to an element

```
<p>Hello <span class="animate__animated animate__bounce">there!</span</p>
```

Here is the website the information was taken: https://animate.style/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the animation needs to be applied to a `block` or `inline-block` element. A span element is an `inline` element by default. So, you need to either add CSS to make the `span` `display: inline-block` or move the class to the `p` tag.

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.0.0/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p>Hello <span class="animate__animated animate__bounce">there!</span</p>
```